# Look for highest number and then insert the column heading

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In one worksheet I have different columns for each stock item and their % market share in the rows below.
In another worksheet, I want a formula that will search each row in previous sheet, find the highest percentage in that row and then instead of pulling the percentage, I want it to show the product name.

I have done this:
=MAX('March Competitors'!D3:Z3)
but don't know how to finish the command that says show me the column heading instead of the highest %.

Any ideas?
TIA

Comment: What row has the product name, seems like an INDEX/MATCH would do this.

Answer (score 0):

If the column heading is in row 2, it would be something like

```
=INDEX('March Competitors'!D2:Z2,,
   MATCH(MAX('March Competitors'!D3:Z3),
     'March Competitors'!D3:Z3, 0))
```

If the column heading is in row 1, it's

```
=INDEX('March Competitors'!D1:Z1,,
   MATCH(MAX('March Competitors'!D3:Z3),
     'March Competitors'!D3:Z3, 0))
```